# The Yeoman Generator encounters a failure with the error message "Trying to copy from a source that does not exist."

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, yeoman, web-parts, spfx

I am trying to generate SharePoint Framework (SPFx) client-side web parts using the Yeoman SharePoint Generator, but it consistently presents the same error as detailed below.

```
C:\Users\utkarsh>yo @microsoft/sharepoint

     _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
    |       |    │ Welcome to the Microsoft │
    |--(o)--|    │      365 SPFx Yeoman     │
   `---------´   │     Generator@1.18.1     │
    ( _´U`_ )    ╰──────────────────────────╯
    /___A___\   /
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `

See https://aka.ms/spfx-yeoman-info for more information on how to use this generator.
Let's create a new Microsoft 365 solution.
? What is your solution name? testsln
? Which type of client-side component to create? WebPart
Add new Web part to solution testsln.
? What is your Web part name? testflow
? Which template would you like to use? No framework
Overwriting an existing "package.json"

Error @microsoft/sharepoint

Trying to copy from a source that does not exist: C:\Users\utkarsh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@microsoft\generator-sharepoint\lib\generators\solution\templates\base\.vscode\settings.json
```

**Developer environment**

Windows 10 Pro 64 bit

**Environment details**

- Node JS - v18.18.2
- NPM - 9.8.1
- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint - 1.18.1
- gulp-cli - 2.3.0
- yo - 4.3.1